# Delete Git repository using SourceTree without deleting files on disk

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I have created new repository using SourceTree in mac book root accidentally.
 Now git status showing huge list(280800 approx) of tracked files including desktop, documents and download directories and subdirectories and their files etc.

Every time when we delete repository through SourceTree its show below message.

[image]

Actually i'm newbie in git so just want to know that if we delete repository so that will also delete all those files from HardDrive or not.

Can you please suggest.

Thanks,
Sneh

Comment: easiest way would be to delete the .git folder in your root directory, just to make sure - afterwards, SourceTree should notice that the repository no longer exists

Comment: Yes, That make sense as i won't require repo anymore so i can remove .git folder and then i can simply remove repo using **Remove Bookmarks**.

Comment: Thanks, It worked

Answer (score 0):

Click the **Remove Bookmarks**. This will remove the link to repo from source tree but the files will be there on disk.

If you are worried about ignoring those million files from your repo. Create a gitignore or global gitignore. Follow the [github link](https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files/#create-a-global-gitignore)

Comment: Does .gitignore file require commit after necessary changes and as per @Florian Koch suggestion, I think we can simply remove .git folder ?

Comment: Does not require commit.